# Sending IV in WebCrypto AES

Tags: javascript, security, encryption, cryptography, webcrypto-api

I am trying to transport a message across an unsafe transport boundary using AES-CBC. I generated the IV (on the sender's side) using crypto.getRandomValues. 
I am then encrypting the message using crypto.subtle.encrypt. As part of the message I plan to append the IV and send it to the receiver. Is it safe from a security perspective to transport the IV (while using AES-CBC) unencrypted?

Comment: If you're asking whether the IV must be secret, then the answer is [**no**](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/23993/ivs-for-different-aes-encryption-modes).